# Websites that archive cross-browser, cross-platform css/js bugs?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I'm about to develop my own browser inconsistency/bug compendium site but I'm wondering if I really need to - can we get a wiki of sites that do this already? I'm aware of a lot of them but I hope I'm not missing out on some major ones.

I wanted mine to be more intuitive and social-like for most people, powered by tags and screenshots and test-case pages.

Answer (score 20):

**Non-Mobile:**

- http://www.brunildo.org/test/
- http://www.gtalbot.org/BrowserBugsSection/
- http://www.quirksmode.org/
- http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/
- http://www.positioniseverything.net/
- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css
- http://www.richinstyle.com/bugs/
- http://haslayout.net/
- http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Main_Page
- https://web.archive.org/web/20100323052222/http://channel9.msdn.com/wiki/wiki/InternetExplorerSupportForCSS/
- https://web.archive.org/web/20100125012019/http://channel9.msdn.com/wiki/wiki/InternetExplorerBugs
- http://css-class.com/test/bugs/ie/ie-bugs.htm
- http://perfectionkills.com/category/cft/ (and http://kangax.github.com/cft/)
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/
- http://www.css-lab.com/
- http://www.iecss.com/ ( Jonathan Neal's roundup of default IE styles )
- http://marc.baffl.co.uk/bugs.php
- http://dev.moonhenge.net/bugs/
- http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/search/label/IE7
- http://www.enhanceie.com/ie/bugs.asp
- http://dean.edwards.name/ie7/compatibility/
- https://web.archive.org/web/20101219060238/http://the-dees.webs.com/iepp1
- http://edskes.net/ie8overflowandexpandingboxbugs.htm
- http://simon.html5.org/test/ie8rc1-bugs/
- http://magicm.awardspace.com/ie/
- http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/ie8.html
- http://www.designdetector.com/2006/08/ie7-old-bugs-for-new.php
- https://web.archive.org/web/20130531191603/http://jhop.me/ie8-bugs
- https://web.archive.org/web/20100218123106/http://test.rowanw.com/reports

**Mobile:**

- http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/

Answer (score 2):

Not been updated in a while but was good till last year: http://www.webdevout.net/

Comment: Ah, David Hammond's site I forgot about. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that covers browser inconsistencies on File Inputs, w/ a nice color coded table and everything.

http://gordon-myers.com/?p=170

Answer (score 0):

Here are some about my [favorite browser](https://web.archive.org/web/20201125193300/http://www.ihateinternetexplorer.com/) (apart from those already mentioned):

- [9 Most Common IE Bugs and How to Fix Them](https://web.archive.org/web/20131224085745/http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/9-most-common-ie-bugs-and-how-to-fix-them/)
- [Six Things Your Mom Never Told You About Debugging Javascript](https://web.archive.org/web/20100216221224/http://devlunch.smart.fm:80/2009/07/29/six-things-your-mom-never-told-you-about-debugging-javascript/)
- [CSS Compatibility and Internet Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//cc351024%28v=vs.85%29)
- [Internet Explorer Array.sort Unreliable](https://www.zachleat.com/web/array-sort/)
- [Site Compatibility and IE8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ie/site-compatibility-and-ie8)
- [Internet Explorer Programming Bugs](https://channel9.msdn.com/Wiki/InternetExplorerProgrammingBugs)

Answer (score -1):

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/14/css-differences-in-internet-explorer-6-7-and-8/

Comment: smashingmagazine doesn't really cover it as much in-depth as the sites I listed but thanks anyway.